# console error during setTimeout with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, console, requestanimationframe

I have an event listener on `mousewheel`. The script executed should do the following:

- +1 or -1 from a variable depending on the direction of scroll
- not allow said variable to change within 2 seconds after the last change
- use requestAnimationFrame on the `mousewheel` event listener so the browser isn't constantly firing the function

I've read a lot about `requestAnimationFrame` but admittedly I still don't think I understand it fully.

Here is my code:

```
//request animation frame
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60); };
})();


//vars
var pane = 1;
var scrollPause = false;


//user scrolling
function scrolling(e){

  //return if scroll paused
  if (scrollPause) return;

  //scroll up
  if (e.wheelDelta < 0) {
    pane += 1;
    scrollPause = true;
  }

  //scroll down
  if (e.wheelDelta > 0) {
    pane -= 1;
    scrollPause = true;
  }

  //reset scrollPause
  setTimeout(function(){ scrollPause = false; },2000);

  //log pane number
  console.log(pane);
}


//scroll event listener
window.onmousewheel = function(e){ requestAnimFrame(scrolling(e)); }
```

Now this does actually work, but during the setTimeout period, the console repeatedly logs the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.
```

Is this an incorrect way to use requestAnimationFrame? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have the call like this -

```
window.onmousewheel = function(e) { requestAnimFrame(scrolling); }
```

Comment: Yes that gets rid of the error but then e.wheelDelta returns undefined in my scrolling function because I haven't passed the event through.

Comment: The function window.requestAnimationFrame accepts a callback that it calls with certain timestamp and not the event. You might have to change the implementation. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame